# how to create Start and end point straight line using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can you please tell me, how to add the Starting point to end point straight line. And I have added the button to drag the same line to tough the end point to call the method. please tell me I need the code.

Comment: Do you mean drawing a line between start point and end point?

Comment: Yes I mean start point and end point.